# Web2py - Uploading an image

Tags: python, web2py

I have in my controller `default.py`:

```
def images():
    record = db.images(request.args(0))
    form = SQLFORM(db.images, record, deletable=True,
                  upload=URL('download'), fields=['image'])

    if request.vars.image!=None:
#         form.vars.image_filename = request.vars.image.filename
       form.vars.image_filename = "picture_spark_"+str(auth.user.id)
#             form.vars.image_filename = "default"
    if form.process().accepted:
        response.flash = 'form accepted'
    elif form.errors:
        response.flash = 'form has errors'
    return form

def dashboard():
    return dict(img_upload_form=images())
```

In my view `dashboard.html`, I use the form like this:

```
{{=img_upload_form}}
```

However, the problem is that it doesn't work. I choose an image but after I click Submit, there is no change.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean there is no change? Are you going to the dashboard URL with an image record ID as the first URL arg (i.e., to edit an existing record)? Otherwise, you will just be inserting new image records.

Comment: Initially, I added a default picture to all users in my application. So, in this scenario, I guess I am trying to "edit" an existing image. By "no change", I mean: I select the image, click on Submit, page refreshes and there is no update.

Comment: But what is the URL? Is there a record ID in the URL, indicating you are editing an existing record rather than creating a new record?

Comment: Right, I understand what you mean. However, there is no change in the URL. My URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Spark/default/home`. After I select the image and click Submit, it becomes `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Spark/default/home#`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem,
I added a `print record` line to my `default.py` controller.

What I observed was that the output was `None`.

My URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Spark/default/home`. In essence, `home.html` does an AJAX call to `dashboard.html`.

Now, in my controller, I defined it as follows:

```
def dashboard():
    return dict(img_upload_form=images())
```

What I needed to do was return the same form for `home.html`

```
def home():
    return dict(img_upload_form=images())
```

This allowed me to successfully upload images!